# Error when trying to pip install dedupe "No matching distribution found"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pip, anaconda, python-dedupe

I am trying to install dedupe from Jupyter Notebooks. Python version is 3.11.5.

```
pip install dedupe --proxy http://...
```

I am getting the following error even though setuptools is already installed. Is this due the version of setuptools that is installed?

[image]

Comment: No, you have a `ConnectionTimeoutError`. Either a slow internet connection or something wrong in your settings